# Mongodb very verbose despite log configuration set to 0

Tags: mongodb, logging

My MongoDB instance produces gigabytes of logs (through the QUERY component) even though I set the global verbosity level to 0 and all components to -1 (verbosity inheritance).

This is a very bad impact on the instance's performance.

Below is a sample of the logged records, the output of db.stats() and of db.getLogComponents().

PS / EDIT - since I'm already seeing a vote down... : I've already tried everything I could find online (using a yaml config file with quiet = true, I checked that the profiling level was at 0, I even tried setting the Log Component to 0 explicitely, but nothing works, mongo is still logging those queries massively...)

Any idea as to why mongo keeps producing these log entries? Any suggestions to turn that off? Thanks.

2016-02-23T09:14:27.089+0100 I QUERY    [conn526] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 730309037 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:2 reslen:1114 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 268ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.089+0100 I QUERY    [conn546] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:4 reslen:232 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.089+0100 I QUERY    [conn532] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: -1176121626 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:3 reslen:2162 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 268ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.089+0100 I QUERY    [conn533] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: -1452854181 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:1 reslen:888 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.089+0100 I QUERY    [conn529] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 401721954 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:2 reslen:776 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.091+0100 I QUERY    [conn524] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: -73774731 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:1 reslen:311 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.195+0100 I QUERY    [conn534] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:4 reslen:232 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 278ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.203+0100 I QUERY    [conn525] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:4 reslen:232 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 268ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.204+0100 I QUERY    [conn528] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 401721954 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:2 reslen:776 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.204+0100 I QUERY    [conn547] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 196127445 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:2 reslen:1004 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.204+0100 I QUERY    [conn535] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: -1176121626 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:3 reslen:2162 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.205+0100 I QUERY    [conn544] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 401721954 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:2 reslen:776 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms
2016-02-23T09:14:27.207+0100 I QUERY    [conn543] query jdigger.stacktraces query: { hashcode: 1 } planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:51110 cursorExhausted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:399 nreturned:4 reslen:232 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 800 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 400 } } } 269ms

> db.stats()
>   {
>           "db" : "jdigger",
>           "collections" : 2,
>           "objects" : 4821385,
>           "avgObjSize" : 284.73536857147894,
>           "dataSize" : 1372818835,
>           "storageSize" : 395268096,
>           "numExtents" : 0,
>           "indexes" : 4,
>           "indexSize" : 81928192,
>           "ok" : 1
>   }
>
> db.getLogComponents()
>   {
>           "verbosity" : 0,
>           "accessControl" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "command" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "control" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "executor" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "geo" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "index" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "network" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1,
>                   "asio" : {
>                           "verbosity" : -1
>                   },
>                   "bridge" : {
>                           "verbosity" : -1
>                   }
>           },
>           "query" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "replication" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "sharding" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "storage" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1,
>                   "journal" : {
>                           "verbosity" : -1
>                   }
>           },
>           "write" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           },
>           "ftdc" : {
>                   "verbosity" : -1
>           }

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this should be considered a workaround or an actual solution but I was able to reach my goal i.e reduce the general logging overhead by using db.setProfilingLevel(0, 1000).

As someone pointed out, Mongo seems to profile the "longlasting" queries per default, regardless of the Profiling Level setting or any other parameter.

Since most of my queries were 200 ms queries, setting the threshold at 1 second did the trick for me. Given the implementation details of my use case, the 200ms where not necessarly shocking, so that's where I didn't really fit in the "norm".

Comment: FYI, the equivalent parameter for the `mongod` config file is [`slowOpThreshholdMs`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs). You have numerous slow collection scans (COLLSCAN) where an index might be beneficial .. but it sounds like this is acceptable for your use case. You can also adjust the `slowms` value at runtime, which is the effect of the second parameter to `db.setProfilingLevel()` in your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post, I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's profiler automatically logs any queries which take longer than 100ms, so it could be that. You can switch it off, by using `db.setProfilingLevel(0)` - see documentation at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

However, I'd also consider adding an index to your collection which is optimised for your query, because right now, the query is reading every record in the collection (COLLSCAN).